# Iframe problem and overlay

Tags: javascript, iframe, overlay

I am using an iframe to embed content from another site. The button in the iframe opens an overlay with a form. The problem is when the button is clicked, the overlay does not open fully. The problem is not from the overlay but from the iframe and parent.

The site i am testing on is at www.sycotickets.com/form.php. you can check it and click on the button at the bottom to see the problem. I also learnt javascript can be used to embed. Can anyone please pint me in the right direction on both issues?

Comment: What browser are you testing in? In Firefox, the "What features would you like to see" is half-hidden off the bottom of my screen...

Comment: i am using google chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possible answers when using AJAX to load page content from a different server

1) Both servers are in a similar domain (`s1.example.com`, `s2.example.com`) in which case, you can set the domain to simply be `example.com` which allows full functionality withing AJAX calls.

2) Servers are on completely different domain - The server which provides the content (currently for the IFrame) must provide the data using the `JSONP` protocol (note the P!) this means the resulting data is loaded into a script tag which then executes. The data itself contains a JS function call eg:

```
{data: '<pre>Some Html</pre>'}
```

is actually returned as:

```
function SomeFuncNameSpecifiedInTheRequest({data: '<pre>Some Html</pre>'});
```

Instead of doing an AJAX call, you dynamically add a script tag to the page, something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http:/www.example.com/GetMyData.php?WrapperFunction=SomeFuncNameSpecifiedInTheRequest">
```

You then implement `SomeFuncNameSpecifiedInTheRequest` on your page and process the results when it's called. JQuery implements this functionality for you automatically (at least the client-side bit.)

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp) for more information on JSONP and [here](http://jszen.blogspot.com/2005/03/cross-domain-security-woes.html) for more information on setting the domain

Comment: I am not using ajax to load the content. It is embedded with an iframe.

Comment: @sammville I understand that but for the reasons mentioned in the other answer, an IFrame i just that - a frame, you can't break out of it. The only thing you can do is use Javascript and AJAX to load the content directly into the main page. It's a better user experience, you have more control and it's also much better practice. IFrames are considered evil :)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing you can do really. If it's loading from an external site browsers prevent you as a developer from accessing other sites and modifying them to try and prevent XSS attacks. You *could* try to fake it by moving the iframe where you want it dynamically and overlaying the black on click on your end... but that seems pretty kludgy...

Comment: the two sites are mine! the site delivering and site i am using to test. The overlay is loaded from the other site but it does not work well when i embed it into another page.

Comment: I might be missing something... but the source code shows the iframes not being on the same domain? You have your main domain: "sycotickets.com" and in the source the iframe says: "poplytics.com". Is that not correct?

Comment: yes it is correct. I am in control of the two sites. I am testing poplytics.com on sycotickets.com

Comment: As the other poster said you'd need to make the domains the same then or use JSON on one and do a JSONP call, but that's outside of the scope of your question :\